# VBA function forcing recalculation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a DLL that I'm calling through an Excel VBA function using a subroutine containing `Declare Function <func> Lib`. In order to control the location of the dll, I'm using `Application.VBE` to create a module at run time that contains the function reference (a bit messy, but the only solution that seemed to work).

Everything works fine, but modifying modules has the unwelcome consequence that the cell is marked as dirty immediately after evaluation causing i) no result to be written to the cell and ii) immediate revaluation of the function.

Is there a way to prevent a function from dirtying the cell?

pseudo-code (actual code is pretty horrible)

Module1:

```
Function main()
  newModule = Proj.vbcomponents.Add(1).CodeModule.AddFromString(stng)
  main = module2.callDll()
End Function
```

Module2 (contained within stng):

```
Declare Function <func> Lib
Function callDll()
  callDll = func
End Function
```

I am calling the function in a worksheet cell using `=main()`

Thanks!

Mat

UPDATE

I have tried converting to manual calculation, but this doesn't seem to solve either problem described above. The following code demonstrates the problem

```
Function main()
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Dim stng As String
  stng = _
  "Function callDll()" & Chr(13) & _
  "callDll = 1" & Chr(13) & _
  "End Function"
  On Error Resume Next
  ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(6)
  On Error GoTo 0
  ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule).CodeModule.AddFromString (stng)
  main = Module2.callDll()
End Function

Function mainAlt()
  mainAlt = Module2.callDll()
End Function
```

A worksheet call to `=main()` returns zero but a call to `=mainAlt()` returns the correct result (one)

Note that 'visual basic for applications extensibility...' needs to be enabled as a reference for this to work, and i've lazily assumed that the created module will have index 6.

Cheers

Comment: What is `module2`? How is newModule declared?

Comment: it's created at runtime, the code for it is contained in 'stng'.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off calculation beforehand:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
```

When you're ready, you can force a calculation with...

```
Application.Calculate
```

...and then turn it back on with:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately that approach doesn't seem to work as the formula doesn't return a result and the dirty property seems to override manual calculation, forcing a recalculation anyway. I've updated the question to be more clear.